# Why is retainAll not accurately computing the intersection of two sets?

Tags: java, set, intersection, java-6, retain

I'm using Java 6.  I can't figure out why "retainAll" is not correctly computing the intersection of two sets.  I have

```
for (ProductDto dtoProd : dto.getProducts())
{
    System.out.println("dtoProd:" + dtoProd.getId());
}   // for
for (ProductDto princProd : principal.getProducts())
{
    System.out.println("princProd:" + princProd.getId());
}   // for
dto.getProducts().retainAll(principal.getProducts());
```

Despite the fact I observe through my System.out's that I have the same products in both sets, after, the last call, my "dto.getProducts()" is empty.  This is the relevant object's id and hashcode methods, if that matters ....

```
@Override
public int hashCode()
{
    return this.id != null ? this.id.hashCode() : 0;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj)
{
    boolean ret = false;
    if (obj instanceof ProductDto)
    {
        final ProductDto other = (ProductDto) obj;
        ret = (this.id == other.getId() || (this.id != null && this.id.equals(other.getId())));
    }
    return ret;
}
```

and here is the System.out info

```
dtoProd:777
dtoProd:778
dtoProd:110074257z
princProd:777
princProd:777SB
princProd:110074257z
princProd:110074258z
princProd:110074259z
princProd:6161
princProd:778
```

What else do I need to do to compute the correct intersection?

Comment: What is `id`? Post a [mcve], with complete sample objects.

Comment: Id is a java.lang.String

Comment: Then post a short example that we can copy-paste, run and see the results.